# $.post never receives a response

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, post

I'm a fairly inexperienced coder, and am seeking help on why I'm not receiving a response to my $.post command.

From the output, (i think) the post is correctly submitting the PHP page, and the PHP correctly creates a JSON file with the values I expect. The issue is that my  callback never seems to fire.

I never receive a log message of "Function Response", therefore, I don't think the post is ever entering the callback.

I've read lots and lots, and attempted a bunch of solutions, including some AJAX. But after about 10 hours, I'm stumped. My $.post is based on the this guide: [Save JavaScript variables to PHP/MySQL DataBase Securely with Ajax Post](https://html-online.com/articles/javascript-variable-php-mysql-ajax-post-json/)

Thanks for any help you can shed on this.

I'm testing the code on a Windows most recent WAMP Server.

index.php (relevant bit)

```js
$('#radarDropdown').change(function () {
    currentRadarId = $('#radarDropdown').val();
    var radSel = document.getElementById('radarDropdown');
    var currentRadarName = radSel.options[radSel.selectedIndex].text;
    document.getElementById('radarSelectedLabel').innerHTML = currentRadarId;
    document.getElementById('radarSelectedName').innerHTML = currentRadarName;
    getBacks(currentRadarName, processResponse);
//  getBackground(currentRadarName);
    console.log('Start request');
                
//  document.getElementById('returnBackground2').innerHTML = back1;
//     get background image filename for this radar.
});

function getBacks(currentRadarId, callbackFn) {
    console.log('Enter getBacks');
    $.post(
            "getBackgrounds.php",
            {radarBOMId: currentRadarId},
            function(response) {
              console.log('function response');
              processResponse(response);
            },'json');
};
          
function processResponse(response){
    console.log('Entered processResponse');
    console.log(response);
    var backgroundFile = response.background;
    var locationsFile = response.locations;
    var roadsFile = response.roads;
    var riversFile = response.riverBasins;
    var railFile = response.rail;
    var rangeFile = response.range;
    var topoFile = response.topography;
    var catchFile = response.catchments;
    var wthrDistrictsFile = response.wthrDistricts;
    var waterwaysFile = response.waterways;
    document.getElementById('returnBackground2').innerHTML = backgroundFile;    
    };
});
```

getBackrounds.php:

```html
<?php
header('Content-type: application/json');

require_once('dbconnect.php');

$typesArray = array(
        'background',
        'catchments',
        'locations',
        'rail',
        'range',
        'riverBasins',
        'roads',
        'topography',
        'waterways',
        'wthrDistricts',
    );

$idval = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $_POST['radarBOMId']);

foreach ($typesArray as $i => $value) {
    $sql = 'SELECT backfilename, backtype FROM InUseRadarsBackgroundsView WHERE productidbom ="'. $idval. '" and backtype = "'.$value.'"';
    $result = $connection->query($sql);
    
    $response = array();
    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            $response[$value] = $row["backfilename"];
            //console.log('Processed row ' & $i);
    }
    echo json_encode($response);
    } else {
        echo "  0 results";
    }
}
?>
```

POST response:

```html
{"background":"IDR503.background.png"}{"catchments":"IDR503.catchments.png"}{"locations":"IDR503.locations.png"}{"rail":"IDR503.rail.png"}{"range":"IDR503.range.png"}{"riverBasins":"IDR503.riverBasins.png"}{"roads":"IDR503.roads.png"}{"topography":"IDR503.topography.png"}{"waterways":"IDR503.waterways.png"}{"wthrDistricts":"IDR503.wthrDistricts.png"}
```

Comment: add other callbacks to be called when the error happens to see what is going on. maybe something fails and your success callback is never called.

Comment: Some sensible code indentation would be a good idea. It helps us read the code and more importantly it will help **you debug your code**
[Take a quick look at a coding standard](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-2/) for your own benefit. You may be asked to amend this code
in a few weeks/months and you will thank me in the end.

Comment: Add `ini_set('display_errors', 1); ini_set('log_errors',1); error_reporting(E_ALL); mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);` to
the top of your script. This will force any `mysqli_` errors to
generate an Exception that you can see on the browser and other errors will also be visible on your browser.

Comment: Look at your PHP script, there are some fairly OBVIOUS errors (now I have formatted the script sensibly)  in the use of `}` which are almost definitely crashing that script.

Comment: Thanks. Yeah, I'm echoing each loop. Thanks... now to work out how to push the key value pairs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not the complete answer, but try to add other callbacks (e.g. fail callback) to check if some errors occur when you make this POST. Here is an example of how this can be done :

```
$.post( "example.php", function(data) {
  alert( "success" );
})
.fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus) {
  alert( "Request failed: " + textStatus );
})
.always(function() {
  alert( "finished" );
});
```

Comment: Good suggestion: I get a response: Request Failed: parsererror.

Comment: parse error suggests you are returning the wrong data type in the response. Looking at your POST response example it is invalid JSON. Can you var_dump $response so we can see what the array looks like.